# Define EQ Instance

Tags: haskell, instance

I am trying to create an Eq Instance, but I have some issues creating it.

I have the following data definitions:

```
data Link = G | S | P deriving (Eq, Show)
data Chain = Empty | Join Link Chain
```

And Now I want to convert Chain into an Eq Instance (True when it is the same).

Here is my current instance:

```
instance Eq Chain where
(Join a b) == (Join c d) = (a == c) && (b == d)
Empty      == Empty      = True
_          == _          = False
```

it marks `(a == c) && (b == d)`as mistake (Ambiguous occurrence ‘==’)

I am unsure why this is, and would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems to be correct, can not produce this locally.

Comment: You did indent this under the `Eq` instance right, not how it is specified here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You failed to indent the method definitions.

```
instance Eq Chain where
↓↓
  Join a b == Join c d = a==c && b==d
  Empty    == Empty    = True
  _        == _        = False
↑↑
```

...Or alternatively, **but highly dis-recommended**, put them in braces

```
instance Eq Chain where {
Join a b == Join c d = a==c && b==d;
Empty    == Empty    = True;
_        == _        = False
}
```

Without the indentation or braces, what your code does is declare an *empty* `Eq` instance, and a separate, *completely new* operator that happens to be also called `==`. I.e., you actually wrote this:

```
module Ch where

instance Eq Chain where
  -- missing definitions of `Prelude.==` here

(Ch.==) :: Chain -> Chain -> Bool
Join a b Ch.== Join c d = a==c && b==d
Empty    Ch.== Empty    = True
_        Ch.== _        = False
```

The compiler error tells you that the `a==c` and `b==d` definitions are now ambiguous: is this referring to `Prelude.==` or to `Ch.==`?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner :/ What do you mean by "indent" the method definition?

Comment: You did not leave spaces on the left side of the `==` clauses. See edit.

Comment: @RLP: If you want a description of the rules, check out the Haskell Report [§2.7 Lexical Structure: Layout](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7) for a summary or [§10.3 Syntax Reference: Layout](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3) for more detail. When in doubt, it’s always valid to put a line break and indent after the block keywords `do`, `let`, `of`, and `where`; besides that, indentation is only required when a definition continues across multiple lines.